# Doubts with base adapter class and its functionality

Tags: android

I am trying  for the customized list view,

I am adding the list of objects using array list  and i send it to the class that extends base adapter and when i extends the base adapter class,it implements some methods such as getView etc.

and in the getView i am sending it to the class which assign the names(datas) to customized menu which is in XML

what i want to know is that ,suppose i have a collection of 5 objects and does the getView get called for 5 Objects?

Am i  making it clear to you.

Regards

Rakesh Shankar.P

Answer (score 1):

`Adapter#getView` is only called when the `AdapterView` requires a view. You should not make any assumptions about how frequently or how many times `getView` is called. The only thing `getView` should do is return the required view as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I placed a `Log.d()` in the `getView()` and noticed that `getView()` has been called 5 times.
i.e.  getView() is called for 5objects and therefore 5 `Views` are created. 
And [this tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) says if you have a billion items ,instead of billion `Views` are get created - views will be cached according to the size of the window.