# The Android Spinner in a Listview is sometimes reinitialized

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created an adapter in android :

```
public class PointVerificationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<PointVerification> mObjects;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Dao<ChoixPointVerification, Integer> mChoixPointVerificationDao;
    HashMap<Integer, ReponsePointVerification> mReponses;

public PointVerificationAdapter(Context context,
        Dao<ChoixPointVerification, Integer> choixPointVerificationDao,
        List<PointVerification> ListePointsVerification,
        HashMap<Integer, ReponsePointVerification> listeReponsesPointsVerification) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mObjects = ListePointsVerification;
    this.mChoixPointVerificationDao = choixPointVerificationDao;
    this.mReponses = listeReponsesPointsVerification;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mObjects.size();
}

@Override
public PointVerification getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;

    if (null == convertView) {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.intervention_reponses_list, null);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }

    // affichage du nom du point de vérification
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNom);
    tv.setText(getItem(position).nom);

    Integer idChoixPointVerification = null;
    Integer idPointVerification = getItem(position).id;
    if (mReponses != null && mReponses.containsKey(idPointVerification)) {
        // affichage du commentaire
        if (mReponses.get(idPointVerification).commentaire != null)
        {
            EditText edCommentaire = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.edCommentaire);
            edCommentaire.setText(mReponses.get(idPointVerification).commentaire);
        }

        idChoixPointVerification = mReponses.get(idPointVerification).idChoixPointVerification;
    }



    // affichage de la liste déroulante
    Spinner spi = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.spiListeChoix);
    ChoixPointVerificationDal choixPointVerificationDal = new ChoixPointVerificationDal();
    List<ChoixPointVerification> listeChoixPointVerification;
    try {
        listeChoixPointVerification = choixPointVerificationDal
                .GetByIdPointVerification(mChoixPointVerificationDao,
                        getItem(position).id);

        List<String> pointVerifications = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(ChoixPointVerification choixPointVerification: listeChoixPointVerification)
        {
            pointVerifications.add(choixPointVerification.nom);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                pointVerifications);

        spi.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return row;
}
```

Sometimes when I scroll in the list or access in the EditView, the GetView is called back so the spinner is reinitialized and I lose the user choice. Is there a solution for this ?

**Edit**

well my feeling is that GetView and really called very often and I shouldn't reinit Spinner everytime it goes in that function. But how can I detect if it's the first run of this code ? I had the id the store the position selected with someting like this

```
        spi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                varPosition = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                // your code here
            }

        });
```

but i don't think it's the good way ... :(

**Edit 2**

If I want to create a spinner with the OnItemClickListener. What is the technic ? At the moment I do that :

```
public class PointVerificationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<PointVerification> mObjects;
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
Dao<ChoixPointVerification, Integer> mChoixPointVerificationDao;
HashMap<Integer, ReponsePointVerification> mReponses;
Integer mPositionSelectionne;

public PointVerificationAdapter(
        Context context,
        Dao<ChoixPointVerification, Integer> choixPointVerificationDao,
        List<PointVerification> ListePointsVerification,
        HashMap<Integer, ReponsePointVerification> listeReponsesPointsVerification) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mObjects = ListePointsVerification;
    this.mChoixPointVerificationDao = choixPointVerificationDao;
    this.mReponses = listeReponsesPointsVerification;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mObjects.size();
}

@Override
public PointVerification getItem(int position) {
    return mObjects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;

    if (null == convertView) {
        row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.intervention_reponses_list, null);
    } else {
        row = convertView;
    }

    // affichage du nom du point de vérification
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvNom);
    tv.setText(getItem(position).nom);

    Integer idPointVerification = getItem(position).id;
    if (mReponses != null && mReponses.containsKey(idPointVerification)) {
        // affichage du commentaire
        if (mReponses.get(idPointVerification).commentaire != null) {
            EditText edCommentaire = (EditText) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.edCommentaire);
            edCommentaire
                    .setText(mReponses.get(idPointVerification).commentaire);
        }

    }

    // affichage de la liste déroulante
    Spinner spi = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.spiListeChoix);
    spi.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.intervention_reponses_list, null);

            ChoixPointVerificationDal choixPointVerificationDal = new ChoixPointVerificationDal();
            List<ChoixPointVerification> listeChoixPointVerification;
            try {
                listeChoixPointVerification = choixPointVerificationDal
                        .GetByIdPointVerification(mChoixPointVerificationDao,
                                getItem(position).id);

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        pointVerifications);

                spi.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });



    return row;

}
```

**Edit 3**

The layout of the activity containing the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstPointsVerification"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the listview for each line of the Listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNom" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/ListePrincipal"
  />

   <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spiListeChoix"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" />


  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edCommentaire" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    style="@style/ListePrincipal"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

My objective is just to create a list of point to verificate by the user. He'll have about 20 lines to verify. Each line contains a label, a spinner with the difference choice and a comment field. I'll have to retrieve each answer on each line then.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing a correct thing by putting a spinner inside of the getView() ?? may be you want something like OnItemClick and then rebuild your spinner??

Comment: well you probably right i'll look how to do that ... tk you

Comment: Here is an answer from another post about the number of calls of getView() --- Adapter#getView is only called when the AdapterView requires a view. You should not make any assumptions about how frequently or how many times getView is called. The only thing getView should do is return the required view as quickly as possible. Taken from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287563/doubts-with-base-adapter-class-and-its-functionality. ---- Why would you want to check the first run of the code? Perhaps you should give more insight on your flaw after you create the Adapter then itemclicks....

Comment: no problems man. glad to be helpful.

Comment: do you have an example for creating into the item click ? can you answer to the question so I can mark you as the answerer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of OnItemClick for a listview. You should move your spinner creation 
elsewhere rather into a separate method. Then call it upon the itemclick like it's 
done here

```
ListView mainListview = new ListView(this);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,  new String[]{"Search","Options"});
            mainListview.setAdapter(adapter); /// your adapter here
            mainListview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {

        ///doYourSpinnerStuff(arg1) here

                    }

                            });
```

This whole piece of code below should be moved elsewhere - rather into a separate 
method. Then you create a spinner then you populate it upon a click. 
Can you show a sketch - a screenshot or a layout how to want to position your views in your activity.

```
// affichage de la liste déroulante
    Spinner spi = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.spiListeChoix);
    ChoixPointVerificationDal choixPointVerificationDal = new ChoixPointVerificationDal();
    List<ChoixPointVerification> listeChoixPointVerification;
    try {
        listeChoixPointVerification = choixPointVerificationDal
                .GetByIdPointVerification(mChoixPointVerificationDao,
                        getItem(position).id);

        List<String> pointVerifications = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(ChoixPointVerification choixPointVerification: listeChoixPointVerification)
        {
            pointVerifications.add(choixPointVerification.nom);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                pointVerifications);

        spi.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: so if the user click on the spinner in the listview the onitemclick of the listview will be called ? it sounds rather complicated

Comment: Noo. Your PointVerificationAdapter  is created for a listview or another spinner right? So basically when either of this listview or spinner is created you set OnItemClick for them and basing on that click you create your extra spinner. I hope I got you right...

Comment: PointVerificationAdapter is for the Spinner. I have another adapter for the ListView. I'm a bit lost, how do you create the spinner into the onitemclick ? I'll edit the question to reflet the state of my work. And thank for your help, really.

Comment: I can't test it now :( but i'll put my current layout in the question